# Increasing timeout WCF calling ASMX

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asmx

I have a WCF service which consumes an asmx web service. Calls to the web service sometimes timeout. How do I increase the timeout value, ideally in the webconfig.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust the execution timeout within your web.config.

[HttpRuntimeSection.ExecutionTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.executiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The ExecutionTimeout property indicates the maximum number of seconds a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET. The default is 110 seconds. This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the  element is set to false.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="60"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks - Just to clarify, I had this to my WCF webconfig and it will change the timeout between WCF and the ASMX?

Comment: For the WCF client that is consuming the ASMX web service, I believe you will need to adjust the session timeout. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You could also adjust the receive timeout for the binding in the client congif file.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this in your Web.config inside...

1) `<system.web>`

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="4194304" maxQueryStringLength="2048" executionTimeout="360" />
```

2) `<basicHttpBinding>`

```
<binding name="uploadFilesBasicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:10" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00">
```